# Two UIWebViews, how to set the second webview so when links are clicked it sends them to the first webview to load?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

This question may seem a little odd/weird, but I have two UIWebViews, one of which is set to hidden in the .xib file, and it's delegate set to my view controller. The 2nd UIWebView is used to parse and "cleanup" the html from the hidden UIWebView and display it as a "mobilized" page to the user. There is no delegate on the non-hidden UIWebView in my .xib file.

The problem I'm having is that when the 2nd UIWebView finishes loading, the user taps on a link within the 2nd UIWebView, and it finishes loading the non parsed webpage because it didn't send this link click back to the hidden UIWebView to be loaded so that the 2nd UIWebView can parse it when it finishes loading. My two UIWebView's are properties in my .m file.

Is there any way I can solve this? I appreciate any responses offered! If i haven't stated my question clearly, please let me know!

Some code:

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Web : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *url;

@end
```

.m:

```
#import "Web.h"

@interface  Web()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *output;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *wrapper;

@end

@implementation Web

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{   
    if(webView == self.webView2)
    {
        [self.webView loadRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.webView loadRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request];
    }
    return NO;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:self.url]];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{   
    [self cleanUp];

    [self.webView2 loadHTMLString:self.output baseURL:nil];
}

- (void)cleanUp
{
    NSString *input = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById(\"ctl_ctl_cphBody_cphCenter_divHtml\").innerHTML;"];

    NSString *breadcrumbString = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByClassName('breadcrumb')[0].outerHTML;"];

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        self.wrapper = @"<html><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=UTF-8\"/><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale = 1.37,maximum-scale = 2.0\"/></html>";
    }
    else
    {
       self.wrapper = @"<html><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html;charset=UTF-8\"/><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"initial-scale = 0.57,maximum-scale = 2.0\"/></html>";
    }

    self.output = [NSMutableString stringWithString:self.wrapper];
    [self.output insertString:input atIndex:147];

    [self.output replaceOccurrencesOfString:breadcrumbString withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [self.output length])];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

This lets you intercept load requests and cancel them. You can then grab the URL from the request and hand it off to your hidden webview. The only caveat is, IIRC, this method will be called even for requests that you load yourself with `-loadRequest:`, so you'll want to check the `navigationType` argument.

Comment: I was able to grab the requested url from the 2nd webview and feed it into the hidden webview, but its not working correctly; my NSLog is saying that the requested url is about blank and it goes ahead and loads it, but it doesn't "mobilize" the loaded webpage.

Comment: To be specific, when I try this code: `[self.webView loadRequest:self.webView2.request];` it loads a blank page with only my wrapper NSString with no content.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`. Forward the request to the first webView and return `NO` to prevent the second webView from loading the page.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this some more please? I edited my code above with the `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` method above, but it's not working for me.